# Sequelize Query - Count associated tables and count all for pagination

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

this is my first question on stackoverflow, never used it before but this issue is making me tear my hair out.

I'm building an infinite scroll component for a react app I'm working on a I'm trying to make a Postgres DB query work.

I have 2 tables - Challenges, and UserChallenges.

Challenges **have many** User Challenges.

I need to get a subsection of Challenges (from start to end) with each Challenge having a count of the number of "participants" (number of associated UserChallenges), and also a count of all challenges.

Something like this:

```
{
rows: [Challenge, Challenge, Challenge],
count: n
}
```

Where each challenge includes the total number of userChallenges as "participants" and count is a count of all challenges.

Here is the query:

```
let json_query = {
    attributes: { 
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("user_challenges.id")), "participants"]] 
    },
    include: [{
        model: UserChallenge, attributes: []
    }],
    order: [['timestamp', 'DESC']],
    offset: start, 
    limit: end
  }
```

The **start** and **end** quantities are the start and end of the pagination.

I'm running this query as follows:

```
var challengeInstances = await Challenge.findAndCountAll(json_query)
```

This results in the following error:

```
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  
parent: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_challenges"
```

and this is the sql it's saying it's running:

```
`SELECT "challenge".* FROM (SELECT "challenge"."id", "challenge".*, COUNT("user_challenges"."id"), "challenge"."participants" FROM "challenges" AS "challenge" GROUP BY "challenge"."id" ORDER BY "challenge"."end_date" DESC LIMIT '4' OFFSET '0') AS "challenge" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_challenges" AS "user_challenges" ON "challenge"."id" = "user_challenges"."challenge_id" ORDER BY "challenge"."end_date" DESC;`,
```

Sequelize or raw queries are both good.
Do let me know if you need any more information and thank you so so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sequelize literal like this & remove object from attributes just paste this code for attributes .

```
attributes: [
    [
        sequelize.literal(`(
        SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM user_challenges
        WHERE 
            // your condition of foreign key like (user_challenges.participants_id = participants.id)
    )`),
        'numberOfParticipants'
    ]
]
```